# Find the Fixed Point from Function

Tags: java

This is the algorithm given to us in our Java class. The objective is to return a fixed point through iteration.

```
INPUT initial approximation p0; tolerance TOL; maximum number of iterations N0.
OUTPUT approximate solution p or message of failure.

Step 1 Set i=1.
Step 2 While i <= N0 do Steps 3-6.
Step 3 Set p=g(p0). (Compute pi.)
Step 4 If |p-p0| OUTPUT (p); (The procedure was successful.)
STOP.
Step 5 Set i=i+1.
Step 6 Set p0=p. (Update p0.)
Step 7 OUTPUT ('The method failed after N0 iterations, N0=', N0);
(The procedure was unsuccessful.)
STOP.
```

But the problem is the code is in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x)
{
return x*x*x*x-3*x*x-3;  //change equation for each problem
}

double g(double x)
{
return pow(3*x*x+3,.25);
}

int main()
{
    double p, p0, Tol;
    int i=1;
    int No;

    printf("Enter approximate p: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &p0);

    printf("Desired Tolerance: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &Tol);

    printf("Maximum Iterations: ");
    scanf ("%d", &No);


    while (i<=No)
    {
        p = g(p0);

        if((fabs(p-p0))<Tol)
        {
            //printf("%lf", &p);
            break;
        }
        printf("Iteration %d: Current value = %lf\n", i, p);

        i++;  //i=i+1
        p0=p;

        if (i>No)
        {
        printf("Method Failed after %d", No);
        printf(" iterations");
        }

    }

}
```

Please help me convert it in Java, since I do not understand the code in C++.

UPDATE: Here's what I finished:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    double p, p0, Tol;
    int i = 1;
    int No;

    System.out.println("Enter approximate p: ");
    p0 = console.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Desired tolerance: ");
    Tol = console.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Maximum Iterations: ");
    No = console.nextInt();

    while(i<=No){
        p = g(p0);

        if((f(p-p0)) < Tol){
            System.out.println("P: " + p);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Iteration: Current Value = " + i + " " + p);

        i++;
        p0 = p;

        if(i>No){
            System.out.println("Method Failed after: " + No);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
public static double f(double x){
    return x*x*x*x-3*x*x-3;
}
public static double g(double x){
    return Math.pow(3*x*x+3, .25);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but SO is not a coding service. So first help us in understanding what have you tried?

Comment: Java and C have very similar syntax.  Begin converting the code to Java.  If you don't know how to translate something, google it first.  If you are still stuck after a legitimate research effort, post a specific question.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm having problem with the pow function.

Comment: Math.pow in Java.  Just google search it.

Comment: @LukePark Just a quick question, is this part of code `3*x*x+3` constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me try to explain what is going on in the original code so you can maybe think up of equivalents in Java.

```
// These are similar to java's import declarations.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* This is a global function, there are no equivalents in java. However,
 * assuming you want to continue working in the static scope of the main
 * function you should make these into static functions */
double f(double x)
{
return x*x*x*x-3*x*x-3;  //change equation for each problem
}

double g(double x)
{
return pow(3*x*x+3,.25);
}

// This is your main function. In java this looks like:
// public static void main(String[] args){}
int main()
{
    double p, p0, Tol;
    int i=1;
    int No;

    // This is a print statement (System.out.printf())
    printf("Enter approximate p: ");
    // This taken in input of type double (signified by %lf)
    // and stores it into p0
    scanf ("%lf", &p0);

    printf("Desired Tolerance: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &Tol);

    printf("Maximum Iterations: ");
    scanf ("%d", &No);


    while (i<=No)
    {
        p = g(p0);
        // fabs gets the absolute value of the passed in value
        // in java this is done my Math.abs()
        if((fabs(p-p0))<Tol)
        {
            //printf("%lf", &p);
            break;
        }
        printf("Iteration %d: Current value = %lf\n", i, p);

        i++;  //i=i+1
        p0=p;

        if (i>No)
        {
        printf("Method Failed after %d", No);
        printf(" iterations");
        }

    }

}
```

Now for the Java. Before you read the following please remember to just try to learn from it rather than hand it strait to your professor. He will likely expect different formatting and/or syntax. You will also be hindering yourself if you do not learn this to the point where you can reproduce it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double p, p0, tol;
        int i=1;
        int no;

        System.out.println("Enter approximate p: ");
        p0 = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Desired Tolerance: ");
        tol = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Maximum Iterations: ");
        no = scanner.nextInt();

        while (i<=no){
            p = g(p0);

            if(Math.abs(p-p0) < tol)
                break;

            System.out.printf("Iteration %d: Current value %f\n", i, p);

            i++;
            p0 = p;

            if(i>no)
                System.out.printf("Method failed after %d iterations\n", no);
        }
    }
    static double g(double x){
        return Math.pow(3*x*x+3, .25);
    }
    static double f(double x){
        return x*x*x*x-3*x*x-3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this part of code `3*x*x+3` constant?

Comment: yes + and * operators work the same in both java and c++ when it comes to int and double types. In c++ you can change what they do but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: how about this one `x*x*x*x-3*x*x-3` ?

Comment: Same thing, you are only using basic mathematical operators. No                                between the two languages.